# Sintaxis de conceptos C++20

Tags: c++, c++20, conceptos

Estoy probando la funcionalidad de conceptos de C++20 con el siguiente concepto:

```
template <typename T, typename ... P>
concept bool es_llamable()
{
    return requires(T &t, P ... p)
    {
        { t(p ...) } -> void;
    };
}
```

Funciona correctamente cuando se evalúa el concepto sobre una función sin parámetros:

```
void f() {}
void g(int) {}

void d(es_llamable &) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    d(f); // muestra 'void d(auto:1&) [with auto:1 = void()]'
    return 0;
}
```

Pero no consigo que funcione sobre una función con parámetros:

```
int main()
{
    d(f);
    d(g); // Error
    return 0;
}
```

El error es el siguiente:

> ```
> error: cannot call function 'void d(auto:1&) [with auto:1 = void(int)]'
>      d(g);
>         ^
> note:   constraints not satisfied
>      void d(es_llamable &) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
>           ^
> note: within 'template<class T, class ... P> concept bool es_llamable() [with T = void(int); P = {}]'
>     concept bool es_llamable()
>                  ^~~~~~~~~~~
> note:     with 'void (& t)(int)'
> note: the required expression 't(p ...)' would be ill-formed
> ```

[Indica que la expresión requerida por el concepto no estaría bien formada](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lKl0JfclwUzrAUOU). Deduzco que es porque el compilador no deduce con qué argumentos será llamada `g`. Así que entiendo que debe ser proveído:

```
template <typename T, typename ... P>
void d(es_llamable<T, P ...> &) { … }
```

Pero este cambio no funciona, además rompe la simplicidad del concepto (haciendo menos atractivo su uso). Cambiando el parámetro y la posición del concepto tampoco funciona:

```
template <typename T, typename ... P>
void d(T &) requires es_llamable<T, P ...>() { … }
```

¿De qué manera debo construir y usar un concepto que compruebe si un parámetro recibido es un objeto que puede ser llamado como una función que devuelve `void` y recibe parámetros arbitrarios?